# Display Media Library Picker Field image in a lists alternate item view in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

So the title pretty much says it all.

I am using Orchard CMS v1.7. I have created my own content type (Product Categories) - this is essentially the same as a page though also has an extra field (Media Library Picker Field) to allow me to select and display a single image - this will be displayed on both the list item view and also the main page content.

I use a projection page to display all content types "ProductCategories". This works well and as expected.

I now want to display this additional image within each of the items in the list of ProductCategories when viewing the projection page.

Using Shape Tracing I created an alternate for my list items.

By default, this looks like this:

```
    @using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@{
    if (Model.Title != null) {
        Layout.Title = Model.Title;
    }

    Model.Classes.Add("content-item");

    var contentTypeClassName = ((string)Model.ContentItem.ContentType).HtmlClassify();
    Model.Classes.Add(contentTypeClassName);

    var tag = Tag(Model, "article");
}
@tag.StartElement
    <header>


        @Display(Model.Header)

        @if (Model.Meta != null) {
            <div class="metadata">
                @Display(Model.Meta)
            </div>
        }
    </header>
    @Display(Model.Content)
    @if(Model.Footer != null) {
        <footer>
            @Display(Model.Footer)
        </footer>
    }
@tag.EndElement
```

I am now stuck - I have no idea how I display the image that is associated to this item.

I step through my code to inspect the content of the `Model` passed into my custom list item view and something strange happens...

when the model is loaded in there is no `ListLogo` inside. - see first snapshot..

[image: - Notice there is no ListLogo within the object -]

However, the moment i step through `@if (Model.Meta != null)` my `ListLogo` can now be found on the object, however it's still empty - as in this snapshot.

[image: - i now have ListLogo though it's empty -]

How do I display the image associated to this content item - there is only 1 too.

Do I need to override creation of the actual list itself? If so, can you give me pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bah - so once again this all comes down to the Placement.info file in my theme.

I added a reference to the `Fields_MediaLibraryPicker` inside my `DisplayType="Summary"` and it worked like a charm.

E.G My placement.info in my theme has this for an item in my list

```
<Match DisplayType="Summary">
    <Place Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary="-"/>
    <Place Parts_Title="-"/>
    <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker="Content:1" /> <!-- this adds the field.. -->       
</Match>
```